# enable other minor mode after calling for my node

Tags: emacs, elisp, minor-mode

I'd like to write minor mode that switches several other modes when run. Some kind of umbrella mode.

Now I'm stack with the simplest task - create mode that enables single other mode.

I'v wrote

```
(require 'whitespace)
(define-minor-mode
  myspace-mode
  "some doc"
  nil
  nil
  (if myspace-mode
    (whitespace-mode 1)
    (whitespace-mode -1)
 )
)
```

When I toggle this mode from M-x nothing happens. But when I evaluate directly (whitespace-mode ±1) it works as expected.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one parameter missing from your definition. For this reason, your `(if ...)` form is actually interpreted as the `keymap` parameter.

Try this:

```
(define-minor-mode
  myspace-mode
  "some doc"
  nil
  nil
  nil
  (if myspace-mode
      (whitespace-mode 1)
      (whitespace-mode -1)))
```